# How to make a transition when using conditional rendering in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, transition

Question details：

- native environment
- I couldn't use `display:none`
- I couldn't use `transition:all`
- I can only use `animate` through a method of js

My render function (not react-native) ：

```
render() { 
    return (
      <View className="container">
        <Touchable onPress={this.pressHandle}>Click</Touchable>
        <View ref="box">
          {this.state.show ? <Text className="show">show Text</Text> : null}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

when I click the component `Touchable`, it whill change `this.state.show`,and conditional render the component `<Text>`

How can I use my animate function ,such as `anmate(){...}` to achieve transition？

I did it like this：(it didn't work)

```
pressHandle(){
  this.setState({
    show:!this.state.show
  });
  this.transitionHandle();
}
transitionHandle(){
  animate(this.refs.box,{
    opacity:1
    // ....
  })
}
```

Comment: Can you provide how function `animate()` is implemented? I never hear about any pure JS animation solution in React Native aside from React Native Animated API.

Comment: @ThoVu NOT ReactNative，`animate(dom,{},function(){   })` , such as `animate(findDOMNode("#id"),{ opacity:0 },() => { console.log("end") });`

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep it rendered in the DOM so that you can apply CSS to it conditionally.

Change this:

```
{this.state.show ? <Text className="show">show Text</Text> : null}
```

To:

```
<Text className="show">show Text</Text>
```

And either change the CSS styles of your ref or add/remove a class name and control the transition completely in CSS.

Comment: see the question details，i can only use the function `animate(){ }`，i can't use `transition:all time`，can not use `tramsorm:xxxx` too.